# Horizonatal alignment with python print / write functions?

Tags: python, formatting, pretty-print

Often I need print lists, dictionaries etc. with nice horizontal alignment (something like tab in MS-Word but **not** `\t` character).

It is not hard to implement function which does it. E.g.

```
def printDictTabed(dct,ntab=10):
    for k,v in dct.items():
        sk  = str(k)
        tab = ' '*max(0,ntab-len(sk))
        print sk,tab,": ",v

printDictTabed({454:99897754545,"x":5454,"john":"whatever"},ntab=6)
```

Output:

```
x       :  5454
john    :  whatever
454     :  99897754545
```

But isn't this possible to do somehow **using standard python formating?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Padding and aligning strings**

By default values are formatted to take up only as many characters as needed to represent the content. It is however also possible to define that a value should be padded to a specific length.

Unfortunately the default alignment differs between old and new style formatting. The old style defaults to right aligned while for new style it's left.

> https://pyformat.info/

**Align right:**

Old

```
'%10s' % ('test',)
```

New

```
'{:>10}'.format('test')
```

**Align left:**

Old

```
'%-10s' % ('test',)
```

New

```
'{:10}'.format('test')
```

your example:

```
def printDictTabed(dct):
    for k,v in dct.items():
        print('{:10}:{:>15}'.format(str(k), str(v)))

printDictTabed({454:99897754545,"x":5454,"john":"whatever"})
```

output:

```
454       :    99897754545
x         :           5454
john      :       whatever
```

Comment: In this context, it should be noted that `%` formatting is more like *very old* formatting. There are now [`f`-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) which can do what `.format()` can do while being faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use [string formating](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples):

```
d= {454:99897754545,"x":5454,"john":"whatever"}

for k, v in d.items():
    print('%-5s:   %-20s' % (k,v))
```

Output:

```
x    :   5454                
john :   whatever            
454  :   99897754545
```